# Why do I get an InteropServices.COMException when attempting to launch QTP from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, com, qtp

This question is a follow-up to the one at [Can I use a language other than VBScript to programmatically execute QTP Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895342/can-i-use-a-language-other-than-vbscript-to-programmatically-execute-qtp-tests). I have a C# (.Net 2.0) program which creates an instance of QuickTest.Application and launches QuickTest Professional (version 10.0). All my development testing worked well.

This morning, I attempted to execute the program from a test machine without the development environment (SharpDevelop 2.2.1). I received an error attempting to execute the program when I double-clicked the Windows icon. The console window flashed too quickly to see what it was, so I dropped down to a command prompt and executed the program from there. Everything worked fine. On the second attempted program launch, and all subsequent ones, I receive a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` which seems to be caused by the COM object throwing an `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT`. The function in question is

```
virtual public QuickTest.Application LaunchQuickTestPro()
{
    QuickTest.Application qtpApp = new QuickTest.Application();
    qtpApp.Launch();
    qtpApp.Visible = false;
    return qtpApp;
}
```

and the `qtpApp.Launch();` line is throwing the exception.

I'm at a complete loss as to what could be wrong. It works fine on the dev machine and worked fine once on the test machine. Rebooting between attempts seems to do no good. I'm fairly new to C#, .NET, and COM, so was hoping someone more experienced here might have seen this before. I'm probably missing something simple.

**UPDATE**: I have discovered this morning, after a reboot, that *the Debug build works fine on the test machine* (no development environment), but *the Release build does not*. I am going to try rebuilding and redeploying. Anyone have a suggestion for build options to examine for the Release build?

**UPDATE2**: It appears that both releases (Debug and Release) work correctly after a fresh reboot. If I try and launch either a second time, I get the error. I've added part of my `Main()` method and my `ExitQTP()` method below.

*I'm wondering if part of the problem is my misunderstanding how `ref` should be used.* However, the code does work every time when run in the IDE (SharpDevelop 2.2.1).

It does appear that something is not being properly cleaned up after the first run, but I don't know what. Looking at the task monitor, the QTP* processes go away as I expect them to. I think there may be a third process that is causing the problem, but haven't been able to isolate what that is,

```
    //Program starts here
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        string configFileName = 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TestPathsConfigFile");

        TextReader configFile = new StreamReader(configFileName);
        QTPLauncher launcher = new QTPLauncher();
        string testName = null; 
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating QuickTest.Application object...");
            QuickTest.Application qtpApp = launcher.LaunchQuickTestPro();
            Debug.WriteLine("Successfully created QuickTest.Application object...");

            while((testName = configFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if((testName != string.Empty) &&
                   (!(testName.TrimStart()).StartsWith(COMMENT_START)))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(testName);

                    launcher.ExecuteQTPTest(testName, ref qtpApp);

                }
            } 

            configFile.Close(); 

           ... //code unrelated to problem removed.

            configFile = null;
            launcher.ExitQTP(ref qtpApp);
        }
        catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ce)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ce.StackTrace);
        }
    }

//Exits QTP
virtual public void ExitQTP(ref QuickTest.Application qtpApp)
{
    qtpApp.Quit();
    qtpApp = null;
}
```

Comment: If I take the ref out of the methods and corresponding calls, it runs successfully several times in a row before failing again with the same error as in the original question.

Comment: Do you autoconnect to QC? That stuff is known to have leaks, or generate other instabilities. We're just in the process of proving that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you are not properly closing (quitting) your QT app instance (if you check your task manager you may see it running) so the subsequent runs fail to initialize properly.

There is a decent blog post where Grant Holliday automates QT for running under Team Build.  Many of the same principles would apply.

http://ozgrant.com/2008/02/28/running-hp-quicktest-professional-ui-tests-with-team-build/

If that's not the issue you'll need to provide more details about what you do with the QT application object.

Comment: I thought so at first, which is why I tried a full reboot. However, it's throwing the exception on first run after reboot. Before that run, I verified that no QTP objects/processes were in memory.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because there is definitely something not closing properly, but it does not seem to be QTP itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Object oQTPapp;

oQTPapp = Server.CreateObject("QuickTest.Application");

Application qtpApp = (Application) oQTPapp;
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.