# UnauthorizedAccessException when using QTObjectModelLib.dll

Tags: c#, qtp

I follow an example from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895342/can-i-use-a-language-other-than-vbscript-to-programmatically-execute-qtp-tests/901364#901364) how to run QTP script from C#. However during Application object creation I get UnauthorizedAccessException. Any clues what might be wrong? Here is a screenshot of the exception and the source code.

[image]

Comment: Check if you can find it back in DCOM Config and tinker with the security settings.  Control Panel + Admin Tools + Component Services.

Comment: Or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558076/office-interop-issue-on-windows-server/7558244#7558244

Comment: DCOM Config doesn't have component with the CLSID mentioned in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 7 or Vista, have a go at starting your development area as Administrator, chances are you're getting an Access Violation.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the OP of the original post you refer to:

> This code did work. However, for QTP version 10.0, I had to change
>   using QTObjectModelLib; to using QuickTest;.

Might help if you are also using version 10.0.