# Office Interop Issue on Windows Server

Tags: c#, com, permissions, windows-server-2008, office-interop

I am trying to access the Word Office Interop on a server from my aplication using the following line:

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();`

This however causes an exception to be throw:

`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).`

Does anyone know what I can do to allow my program to access this?

Comment: Don't automate Office on a server.  It won't work well.

Comment: Could it be that the com library you are targetting is not installed on the server?

Comment: I answered but do agree with SLaks.  Office automation is meant for the desktop not a server.

Comment: @Slaks I have an app that tears up Office docs, scourging them for links and then testing them. I need this to give to all the lazy content owners for dead link policing. I'm running into the same issue - Without an Office installation on the web server I can't use a web/console app to do this work. Any suggestions how to automate the Office format link checking? PDF is cake because you don't need a client (iTextSharp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant permission to 'Launch and Activate' for the user running IIS.

Start-->Run-->dcomcnfg

Under Component Services\Computers Right-Click 'My Computer'

Permissions are under COM Security

Comment: I doesn't find find Microsoft office word 97 -2003 component listed in dcomconfig even thought office is installed there.This is windows 2008 server